# Wrong/ too few output from Qt serial write function

Tags: c++, qt, port, communication

I am trying to send 7 variables that I read before from the GUI with the serial->write...  function to my microcontroller.

I wrote a littile program on my microcontroller that blinks a led if there was an input. But it only shows 5 inputs.

I thougt it might be that my microcontroller is not fast enough and I stalled the Qt programm but that didn´t work.
So I don´t understand why there are too few inputs.

Further I used the qDebug() << function to print out in the console what I send to my microcontroller but this shows only the number of characters I send ( f.e. if I send 500 qDebug() shows "3").
So i guess something with my conversion isn´t correct too.

here is my code:

```
 //conversion from QString into const char*
    q_bauteillaenge      = (ui->Bauteillaenge_e->text());
    q_messintervall_vert = (ui->Messintervall_vert_e->text());
    q_anz_inkrem_vert    = (ui->Anzahl_Inkremente_vert_e->text());
    q_inkrem_laenge_vert = (ui->Inkrementlaenge_vert_e->text());
    q_anz_messungen_vert = (ui->Anzahl_Messungen_vert_e->text());
    q_abs_messungen_vert = (ui->Abstand_Messungen_vert_e->text());

    a_bauteillaenge      =  q_bauteillaenge.toUtf8();
    a_messintervall_vert =  q_messintervall_vert.toUtf8() ;
    a_anz_inkrem_vert    =  q_anz_inkrem_vert.toUtf8() ;
    a_inkrem_laenge_vert =  q_inkrem_laenge_vert.toUtf8() ;
    a_anz_messungen_vert =  q_anz_messungen_vert.toUtf8();
    a_abs_messungen_vert =  q_abs_messungen_vert.toUtf8();

    bauteillaenge      = a_bauteillaenge.constData();
    messintervall_vert = a_messintervall_vert.constData() ;
    anz_inkrem_vert    = a_anz_inkrem_vert.constData() ;
    inkrem_laenge_vert = a_inkrem_laenge_vert.constData() ;
    anz_messungen_vert = a_anz_messungen_vert.constData();
    abs_messungen_vert = a_abs_messungen_vert.constData();


    //Sending
    qDebug() << serial->write("1");
    serial->write("\n");

    qDebug() << serial->write(bauteillaenge);
    serial->write("\n");

    qDebug() << serial->write(messintervall_vert);
    serial->write("\n");

    qDebug() << serial->write(anz_inkrem_vert);
    serial->write("\n");

    qDebug() << serial->write(inkrem_laenge_vert);
    serial->write("\n");

    qDebug() << serial->write(anz_messungen_vert);
    serial->write("\n");

    qDebug() << serial->write(abs_messungen_vert);
    serial->write("\n");
```

Where are my faults ?

Regards

Comment: `QIODevice::write` returns the number of bytes that were written. That's why you get '3' in the log after `qDebug() << serial->write("500")`. If you want to check the string which you're trying to send, you should send it directly to `qDebug()`: `qDebug() << anz_inkrem_vert`.

Comment: Ok I got it, I assumed an other output. But I just added this because I wanted to look if there is maybe a leck why not all variables are send.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would look into the UTF-8 encoding. Are you sure your microcontroller code excepts UTF-8 bytes?
2. How the led is responding to the incoming data depends on the code of your microcontroller. Maybe you can add some microcontroller code.
3. The serial->write function returns the count of the actual written bytes. So it works as it should, but you expected another return value.
   Read the docs about this one:
   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write

Comment: I tested the program on the microcontroller with a terminal (putty) there it works fine.the remote character set is UTF-8 so that should not be the problem.

Comment: The code on the microcontroller is a very simple while loop. I just use a function named UARTgets, this function blocks until an input is read. Is an input read I turn on the led, wait for half a second and turn it off. Thats all in the loop, and I just count 5 blinks of the led, so I suggest the microcontroller receives only 5 of the 7 variables.

Comment: Is your UARTgets function your own function or it it part of a library? From what I get your microcntroller code doesn't make any sense. To debug, put a second (or so) delay between the dispatch of the serial writes in your Qt application. I think you then will get 7 blinks.

Comment: I think the problem is that the data is sent much faster than the microcontroller receives the data. You should get characters from the buffer without any delay. When receiving a newline character you should parse the incoming data. Based on that data you can blink your led. Now your application checks on its own time if theres any data available. If so, blink the led and block the program. Unaware of whats happening during the waiting.

Comment: It´s a library function. The code on the microcontroller is just to test if all variables are received, if it works I will use an other one. I set a Sleep(1000) after eache write. Doesn´t work. I extended the blinks to 5 secs and it also blinks 5 times. when the controller would be too slow then the blinks should be less if I extend the blinking time. So I think the controller is fast enough

Comment: here is the code from my controller:`while(1){

 GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_2);
 SysCtlDelay(50000000);
 
UARTgets(input, sizeof(input));
GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2 | GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);
 SysCtlDelay(50000000);`

Comment: Did you verify the output of the Qt application with a (pc based) terminal?

Comment: Connect the comport you use in your Qt application to another comport with a cabe. The comport can be on the same computer, but also on another computer. Then connect a terminal to the receiving comport.

Comment: I'm searching for a reference for the library functions you mentioned, can't find any. Is there an api or reference document?

Comment: Can´t send you the code from UARTgets function because it is too long.can i add here a zip ? Oh I think I have no USB to USB cable .

Comment: Which microcontroller (and development board) do you use?

Comment: I use a Tiva C Series TM4C123GH6PM from TI. The program is written with the code composer studio.

Comment: an other curious thing is, I added a output like qDebug << bauteillaenge right after I send the endline character "\n". The korrekt output is shown in the Qt console one by one. But the microcontroller starts blinking after all  outputs has been shown.

Comment: The sended variables are correct received. I rewrote thr programm so that the controller blinks green if the input is the expected one, means it has to be send in the correct order. so the first variables are ok. But then it stops somehow.